# Android OpenGLES drawing buffer, blank screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im trying to draw primitives using a FloatBuffer for my vertices and a ShortBuffer for the indexes. Everything works fine with no crashes or warnings but the screen is blank. I can draw with glDrawTexfOES without trouble.
If anyone could take a look at the code I would appreciate it alot.

```
public abstract class PrimitiveBase extends DrawableEntity {
    protected float[] _vertices;
    protected short[] _indices;

    private FloatBuffer _verticesBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer _indicesBuffer;

    public PrimitiveBase(Sprite sprite, float x, float y) {
        super(sprite, x, y);

    }

    protected abstract void setVertices();

    @Override
    public void draw(float x, float y, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
        GL10 gl = GlSystem.getGl();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glScalef(scaleX, scaleY, 1.0F);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _verticesBuffer);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0F, 0, 0, 0);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _indices.length,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indicesBuffer);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    public void load(EntityManager parent) {

        setVertices();

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(_vertices.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        _verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

        _verticesBuffer.put(_vertices);
        _verticesBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(_indices.length * 2);
        ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        _indicesBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
        _indicesBuffer.put(_indices);
        _indicesBuffer.position(0);
    }

}

public class Rectangle extends PrimitiveBase {
    private float _width;
    private float _heigth;

    public Rectangle(Sprite sprite, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(sprite, x, y);
        _heigth = height;
        _width = width;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setVertices() {
        _vertices = new float[8];
        _indices = new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

        _vertices[0] = getX() - (_width / 2);
        _vertices[1] = getY() + (_heigth / 2);

        _vertices[2] = getX() + (_width / 2);
        _vertices[3] = getY() + (_heigth / 2);

        _vertices[4] = getX() + (_width / 2);
        _vertices[5] = getY() - (_heigth / 2);

        _vertices[6] = getX() - (_width / 2);
        _vertices[7] = getY() - (_heigth / 2);

    }

}
```

Comment: And your buffers contain valid values? And your vertices are actually inside your viewing volume?

Comment: Yes its inside the viewing volume the rectangle i create is centered around (0,0), also tried making it VERY big with no result. If the values are valid is a harder question. All the initialization code is in the code above. getX() = 0, getY() = 0..

Comment: How does your projection matrix look like?

Comment: I hope you don't enable blending anywhere, since at the moment your rectangle has an alpha of 0 (don't use `glColor4` if you don't care about the 4th component, or at least be aware of its meaning).

Comment: Will ivestigate when im in front of my own PC.

Comment: Ye have been fiddling with the color, must have forgotten it in that state. Usually have it at 1.0. And thx for the help so far.

Comment: `GL10 gl = GlSystem.getGl();` ?? Are you trying to store the GL handle somewhere and then use it in another thread / not the GL Thread? If so, it will go out of context each time the GL Thread finishes looping and fail